# Brother MFC-295CN Printing improperly after enabling Google Cloud Print

Tags: printing, google

Ok, so here is the thing.
I Have a Brother MFC-295CN that is always connected to my desktop (Ubuntu 11.10 32 Bit) and was printing and scanning perfectly fine until, I decided to try out Google Cloud Print from my Android. Ever since then, things do not print as they have been assigned to. It is printing tiny, and landscape always. I have since disabled Cloud Print on Chromium, signed out of all gmail services, even re-installed the drivers from Brother. But still it is printing improperly. I have an Acer netbook (Ubuntu 11.10 32 Bit) that I have the MFC-295CN installed on and when I Print from that (connected via the USB) it prints perfectly fine. How can I get my Desktop to print normally again?

Thank you for your time and answers.

** Just remembered as well, when in LibreOffice I printed to file rather then Printer, it still printed that document improperly. It did not print to what I specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well turns out for me it was Google Cloud print that caused this. I removed my printer from the Google Cloud Print settings, signed out of Cloud Print from my mobile and printing is back to normal.